# Error returning filename read by tkFileDialog from menu callback in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner in python. I am writing a code with simple GUI, in which there is a menu item "Open" which when clicked asks for image file with ***tkFileDialog***. It does fine to read the filename and path.I want the filename to be returned so that image can be opened and displayed in tkinter Label. But i don't know how to return filename.

here is my code

```
from Tkinter import Frame, Tk, Label, Text, Menu, END, BOTH, StringVar
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy
import tkFileDialog

class DIP(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.parent.title("DIP Algorithms- Simple Photo Editor")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        self.fn=''
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.onOpen)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        print self.fn #prints nothing here
        #self.img=Image.open(self.fn)


    def onOpen(self):

        ftypes = [('Image Files', '*.tif *.jpg *.png')]
        dlg = tkFileDialog.Open(self, filetypes = ftypes)
        filename = dlg.show()
        self.fn=filename
        print self.fn #prints filename with path here


    def onError(self):
        box.showerror("Error", "Could not open file")    

def main():

    root = Tk()
    ex = DIP(root)
    root.geometry("1280x720")
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I even tried by creating an attribute for filename, but no help.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look more closely at your code. You're running `initUI()` before `onOpen()`, and then you are not running `initUI()`, which sets the image, after setting `self.fn`.

To fix this, you need to move your code that changes the image label to another function in your class, like this:

```
def setImage(self):
    print self.fn #prints something now!
    self.img=Image.open(self.fn)
```

Then, at the end of `onOpen()`, you need to call this function.

```
def onOpen(self):
    ...
    self.setImage()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'll need the image in other callbacks too. How can i do this?

Comment: After `self.img` is set once by `setImage(self)`, after it is opened, it should be always available to other callbacks as `self.img`.

Comment: Can you do me 1 more favour. sorry to disturb you again but can you help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291434/how-to-update-image-in-tkinter-label

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is to be expected. When you `print self.fn` in `initUI` the user hasn't selected a file yet. When you print in `onOpen` the user has selected a file, so it displays properly. `self.fn` does get set properly, you are just printing it too early.

If you want to display an image, do so once the user selects a file.

```
def onOpen(self):
    ftypes = [('Image Files', '*.tif *.jpg *.png')]
    dlg = tkFileDialog.Open(self, filetypes = ftypes)
    filename = dlg.show()
    self.fn = filename
    if self.fn: # If a file was selected
        # Display image in label / call display function
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'll need the displayed image in other callbacks too. How can i do this?