# How to update image in tkinter label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner in python so this may be too simple question to ask but i need help..With this code i cannot update image in tkinter label. I can even resize window according to new loaded image's attributes but the new image is not displayed in tkinter label.

```
from Tkinter import Frame, Tk, Label, Text, Menu, END, BOTH, StringVar
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy
import tkFileDialog

class DIP(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    self.parent.title("DIP Algorithms- Simple Photo Editor")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    menubar = Menu(self.parent)
    self.parent.config(menu=menubar)

    #Open Image Menu
    fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Open", command=self.onOpen)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)

    #menu for image ngative
    basicMenu=Menu(menubar)
    basicMenu.add_command(label="Negative", command=self.onNeg)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Basic", menu=basicMenu)

#Image Negative Menu callback
def onNeg(self):
    I2=255-self.I;
    im = Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(I2))
    photo2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    self.label2= Label(self.parent,border=25,image=photo2)
    self.label2.image = photo2 # keep a reference!
    self.label2.grid(row=1, column=2)


def setImage(self):

    self.img=Image.open(self.fn)
    self.I = numpy.asarray(self.img)
    l,h = self.img.size
    text=str(2*l+100)+"x"+str(h+50)+"+0+0"
    self.parent.geometry(text)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
    self.label1 = Label(self.parent,border=25,image=photo)
    self.label1.configure(image=photo)
    self.label1.image = photo # keep a reference!
    self.label1.grid(row=1, column=1)

#Open Callback
def onOpen(self):

    ftypes = [('Image Files', '*.tif *.jpg *.png')]
    dlg = tkFileDialog.Open(self, filetypes = ftypes)
    filename = dlg.show()
    self.fn=filename
    #print self.fn #prints filename with path here
    self.setImage()

#def onError(self):
    #box.showerror("Error", "Could not open file")    

def main():

    root = Tk()
    DIP(root)
    root.geometry("320x240")
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When i run this code, and open an image , it is displayed in label1. But when i open another image again, i' expecting it to be displayed in same label1, but it's not happening. I know the 2nd image is loaded because the window size resized accordingly, the only problem is that it's not being displayed and i cannot figure out why!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating an new `tk.Label` each time `setImage` is called, just create it once outside of `setImage` -- for example, in `initUI`.

You can then change the image by calling `self.label.configure`:

---

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Image
import ImageTk
import numpy as np
import tkFileDialog

class DIP(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("DIP Algorithms- Simple Photo Editor")
        self.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = 1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu = menubar)

        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, border = 25)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, border = 25)
        self.label1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.label2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        #Open Image Menu
        fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label = "Open", command = self.onOpen)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = fileMenu)

        #menu for image ngative
        basicMenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
        basicMenu.add_command(label = "Negative", command = self.onNeg)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Basic", menu = basicMenu)

    def onNeg(self):
        #Image Negative Menu callback
        I2 = 255-self.I;
        im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(I2))
        photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        self.label2.image = photo2 # keep a reference!

    def setImage(self):
        self.img = Image.open(self.fn)
        self.I = np.asarray(self.img)
        l, h = self.img.size
        text = str(2*l+100)+"x"+str(h+50)+"+0+0"
        self.parent.geometry(text)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.label1.configure(image = photo)
        self.label1.image = photo # keep a reference!

    def onOpen(self):
        #Open Callback
        ftypes = [('Image Files', '*.tif *.jpg *.png')]
        dlg = tkFileDialog.Open(self, filetypes = ftypes)
        filename = dlg.show()
        self.fn = filename
        #print self.fn #prints filename with path here
        self.setImage()

    #def onError(self):
        #box.showerror("Error", "Could not open file")    

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    DIP(root)
    root.geometry("320x240")
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @unubtu `self.label1.image = photo # keep a reference!` Why is keeping a reference important?

Comment: @Nancy: Good question. See [Why you must keep a reference to PhotoImages](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm)